# Fetching collections via Mongoose fails(Object {} has no method 'find')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to fetch some collections via Mongoose find method. My model is like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    timeline_content: String,
    timeline_e_id: String

});

var timeline = mongoose.model('timeline', schema);
module.exports = timeline;
```

and with this code i want to fetch some collections:

```
    var Timeline = require('./models/timeline'); 
    var timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.find({timeline_e_id:'an id'}).sort("_id").limit(5).exec(
        function(err, projects) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            //do something
        }
    );
```

But i get this error:

```
TypeError: Object {} has no method 'find'
```

Why? i have to define find method inside my model? Actually i can't find any resource to do queries. This is simplest one but it fails.

Comment: You should be either using `require()` on your module with the definition, or better yet call `var timeline = mongoose.model('timeline')` and it will recall the model from the `mongoose` object.

Comment: How did you define `Timeline` (with capital T) object? I guess it comes from `require`ing the first js file in the question, right?

Comment: @BlakesSeven : i use require and loaded that model already. Save method works but only find doesn't work.
var Timeline = require('./models/timeline');

Comment: @TaoP.R.: i use require and loaded that model already. Save method works but only find doesn't work.
var Timeline = require('./models/timeline');

Comment: @Fcoder  The "point" is that you only call `new TimeLine()` when you want to create a "new" object. And yes the only thing you can do is `.save()` there. Otherwise you call `TimeLine.find()` and not on the instance.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: can you give a more clear answer? i cant understand what i have to do and why

Comment: You have a clear answer. It appeared as I was typing the comment. You **do not** use "new" for any other method than "creating" a new object instance. Just use `TimeLine.find()`. I feel there is an echo in here since I already said that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.find` is a method on your `TimeLine` model, not on an instance of `TimeLine`.

Drop the `new` and the `()` from your variable assignment.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Blakes Seven, your code should look like this:

```
var Timeline = require('./models/timeline');        
TimeLine.find({timeline_e_id:'an id'}).sort("_id").limit(5).exec(
  function(err, projects) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

     //do something
});
```

Comment: can you give a more clear answer? i cant understand what i have to do and why